# can we render div reference stored in useRef variable in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, use-ref, react-tsx

actually i am trying to create a popup which allow user to see expanded view inside the popup when user click on expand view for the particular element there are series of more then one element

Requirment:-the issue is that there are multiple elements, and whenever you click on the element, it should open inside the popup. u can think of it like there is a grid of contacts whenever u click on any of the contact it should be viewed in a popup

my current Approch :-

when user click on the element, i am saving the element refrence to the variable  and trying to pass the refrence as children props

but getting error

suggestion for diffrent approch are welcomed.

thanks in advance

```
import React from "react";

const Summary = () => {

  const [expand, SetExpand] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const expendRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return <div >
    {expand && <><span>hello</span> {
    }<Popup show={expand}>
      {expendRef.current?.parentNode }
    </Popup></>}
     <div ref={expendRef} className='summary-table col-md-6' onClick={()=>SetExpand(!expand)>
             Reference element
     </div>
   </div>
        
}


const Popup=(props)=>{
render(<>
<h1>Popup Element</h1>
<div>{props.children}</props>
<>)

}

export default Summary
```

Comment: assigning a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs) in this way returns the underlying HTML element and not jsx so you can't pass it directly as a child

Comment: you could just pass the actual element as a child instead of passing the ref to the element `<Popup show={expand}> {YOUR_ELEMENT} </Popup>`

Comment: hi @Xiduzo , the issue is that there are multiple elements, and whenever you click on the element, it should open inside the popup. u can think of it like there is a grid of contacts whenever u click on any of the contact it should be viewed in a popup

Comment: please update your question accordingly so we can understand the question better and try and help better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea was really creative and interesting, to put the div inside the popup. I think i did the way you want, but it's a little hacky, i had to create a DOMElement with an append child, weird solution... it would be something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const Summary = () => {
  const [popupVisible, setPopupVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [element, setElement] = useState() as any;

  const showElementOnPopUp = (e: any) => {
    if (!popupVisible) setPopupVisible(true);
    const elementClone = e.currentTarget.cloneNode(true);
    elementClone.querySelector("div").style.display = "block";
    setElement(elementClone);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="summary-table col-md-6" onClick={showElementOnPopUp}>
        Contact 1
        <div style={{ display: "none" }}>
          <p>Number: 111111</p>
          <p>Address: House 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="summary-table col-md-6" onClick={showElementOnPopUp}>
        Contact 2
        <div style={{ display: "none" }}>
          <p>Number: 222222</p>
          <p>Address: House 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="summary-table col-md-6" onClick={showElementOnPopUp}>
        Contact 3
        <div style={{ display: "none" }}>
          <p>Number: 333333</p>
          <p>Address: House 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      {popupVisible && (
        <Popup element={element} setPopupVisible={setPopupVisible}></Popup>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const Popup = (props: any) => {
  const { element, setPopupVisible } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Popup Element</h1>
      <div>
        <DOMElementContainer element={element} />
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setPopupVisible(false);
        }}
      >
        Close Popup
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

const DOMElementContainer = ({ element }: any) => {
  const ref = useRef() as any;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!element) return;
    ref.current.innerHTML = "";
    ref.current.appendChild(element);
  }, [element]);

  return <div ref={ref}></div>;
};

export default Summary;
```

But i think a better approach would be this one, that better uses react state, and is more real, where you would get the list of contacts from some api:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const Summary = () => {
  const [popupVisible, setPopupVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [contactList, setContactList] = useState() as any;
  const [contactInfo, setContactInfo] = useState() as any;

  const someApiCall = () => {
    return Promise.resolve([
      { name: "Contact 1", number: "11111", address: "House 1" },
      { name: "Contact 2", number: "222222", address: "House 2" },
      { name: "Contact 3", number: "333333", address: "House 3" },
    ]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    someApiCall().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);

      setContactList(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {contactList?.map((contact: any) => {
        return (
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setContactInfo(contact);
              setPopupVisible(true);
            }}
          >
            {contact.name}
          </div>
        );
      })}

      {popupVisible && (
        <Popup
          contactInfo={contactInfo}
          setPopupVisible={setPopupVisible}
        ></Popup>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const Popup = (props: any) => {
  const { contactInfo, setPopupVisible } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Popup Element</h1>
      <div>
        <p>Name: {contactInfo.name}</p>
        <p>Number: {contactInfo.number}</p>
        <p>Address: {contactInfo.address}</p>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setPopupVisible(false);
        }}
      >
        Close Popup
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Summary;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is an interesting feature, but I'm sure that you can do it following the React patterns and re-using Components. With that said I will try to answer your question in a simple way.

### The answer to your question:

```
const Summary = () => {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false)
  const expendRef = useRef(null)

  return (
    <div>
      {expand && (
        <>
          <span>hello</span>
          <Popup show={expand} element={expendRef} />
        </>
      )}
      <div 
         ref={expendRef} 
         className="summary-table col-md-6" 
         onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)}
      >
        {'Reference element'}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
const Popup = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Popup Element</h1>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.element.current.outerHTML }} style={{ background: 'red' }} />
     {/* Background red is just to do it obvious, when its render */}
    </>
  )
}
```

### How it works?

By default, React escapes the HTML to cross-site scripting, BUT if you really want to render some HTML, you can use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) property. Then you can take the HTML of your reference, doing `.current.outerHTML`

### Code Example

https://codepen.io/FMadoery/pen/VwdGqwM

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `ref` !

You can do it like as :

```
import React from "react";

const Summary = () => {

   const [expand, SetExpand] = useState<boolean>(false);

   const renderContent = () => (
      <div ref={expendRef} className='summary-table col-md-6' onClick={()=>SetExpand(!expand)>
         Reference element
      </div>
   )

   return (
      <div >
         {expand && <><span>hello</span>
         <Popup show={expand}>
            {renderContent()}
         </Popup></>}
         {renderContent()}
      </div>       
}

export default Summary;
```

Comment: hi @Amr Eraky , the issue is that there are multiple elements, and whenever you click on the element, it should open inside the popup. u can think of it like there is a grid of contacts whenever u click on any of the contact it should be viewed in a popup